# IntelliJ Idea web project automatically deploy static files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3, static-files

I have imported a Maven Project into IntelliJ Idea 13. It's a web project running with an external Tomcat6. How can I set up Intellij Idea to automatically deploy static files from the webapp folder to the exploded war from the target folder?

Netbeans used to do this automatically without any settings to be made. The module is set up as a web module.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a hot deploy of the static resources, the web project should be deployed as an exploded war. 
Please refer:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html and
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html